# How to merge printout preview of 2 worksheets into one preview?

Tags: vba

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Sheet2.PrintOut preview:=True
    Sheet3.PrintOut preview:=True
End Sub
```

So instead of it openly 2 seperate instances of printout previews, it would open one printpreview with sheet2 pages first and sheet 3 pages following up.

I can't find any examples of what this might be related too but thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the sheets to an array and print them

```
Public Sub PrintSheetsWithPreview()
 
    Dim sheetsList As Variant
    
    sheetsList = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetsList).PrintOut preview:=True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much ricardo!